# Gulp-rename: get original file path

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, gulp-rename

I'm using [gulp-rename](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-rename) to rename files.
I want to get files from few directories and put 'em into output directory with some postfix.
This postfix depends on original directory name:

`['/dir/a/style.css', '/dir/b/style.css', '/dir/c/style.css']`
=>
`['/output/style_a.css', '/output/style_b.css', '/output/style_c.css']`

I do something like this:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename'),
    files_list = [
        '/dir/a/style.css',
        '/dir/b/style.css',
        '/dir/c/style.css'
    ];

gulp.src(files_list)
    .pipe(rename(function(path) {
        // extract dir letter:
        var dir_letter = path.dirname.split('dir/')[1].split('/')[0];

        // rename file by changing "path" object:
        path.basename += '_' + dir_letter;
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('/output'));
```

Method `rename` iterates callback for each file.
This callback takes object `path` as argument, which is contains `dirname` property.
**But** `path.dirname` has value `'.'`, instead of original file path like a `'/dir/a/style.css'`.
So, my question is how can I get initial file path inside of `rename` callback?

Comment: Should `some/` be something else in `path.dirname.split('some/')`?

Comment: @MattMS thanks, corrected. I mean `path.dirname.split('dir/')`

Answer (score -1):

From the [gulp-rename docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-rename#notes):

> dirname is the relative path from the base directory set by gulp.src to the filename.

And

> dirname is the remaining directories or ./ if none.

So you may need to use a glob (`/*/`) to make sure it gives you the extra path information in `dirname`.

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename');

gulp.src('/dir/*/style.css')
    .pipe(rename(function(path) {
        // extract dir letter:
        var dir_letter = path.split('dir/')[1].split('/')[0];

        // rename file by changing "path" object:
        path.basename += '_' + dir_letter;
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('/output'));
```

You could also try `gulp.src('/dir/*/style.css', {base: '/'})` if that does not work (see [gulp.src docs](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#optionsbase)).

Answer (score -1):

You can use a new stream to get the path.

```
var Stream = require('stream');
var fileName = '';
function getFileName() {
  var stream = new Stream.Transform({ objectMode: true });
  stream._transform = function(file, unused, callback) {
    fileName = file.path;
    callback(null, file);
  };
 return stream;
}
```

then you can get the file path in rename stream.

```
gulp.src('/dir/*/style.css')
    .pipe(getFileName(fileName))
    .pipe(rename(function(path) {
        console.log(fileName);
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('/output'));
```

Comment: Your code makes no sense, getFileName creates a new stream, and does not accept an argument of fileName?